# How to detect google adsense ad in website by webcrawling

Tags: jsoup, web-crawler, adsense

I need to find out the google adsense ad is exist or not on any website by webcrawling. I am using JSOUP. I got all html tag element except google adsense ad iframe. How can I get this?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can detect these scripts (reg exp) :

```
googlesyndication\\.com/pagead/show_ads\\.js
ad\\.ca\\.doubleclick\\.net
2mdn\\.net
```